# Use check_password function of User with other models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am not using default `User` model for authenticating for some reason.
For password checking I have created same method as `check_password` for my model too but still it always returns `False`.

My code :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    '''
    useranme password fields comes here
    '''


   def check_password(password, encoded, setter=None, preferred='default'):
        """
        Returns a boolean of whether the raw password matches the three
        part encoded digest.
        If setter is specified, it'll be called when you need to
        regenerate the password.
        """
        if password is None or not is_password_usable(encoded):
            return False

        preferred = get_hasher(preferred)
        hasher = identify_hasher(encoded)

        must_update = hasher.algorithm != preferred.algorithm
        if not must_update:
            must_update = preferred.must_update(encoded)
        is_correct = hasher.verify(password, encoded)
        if setter and is_correct and must_update:
            setter(password)
        return is_correct
```

When I call this method using Mymodel instance it return False everytime.

```
user = Mymodel.objects.get(username=username)
user.check_password(raw_password_entered_by_user)
```

Comment: Are you hashing passwords when you save them?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am using make_password function `make_password(pwd)`